# Nvidia and ATI on 13.04 step by step

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati, graphics, multiple-monitors

Im have Dual Xeon system for Photogrammetric related stuff and need setup Ubuntu 13.04 with Nvidia 560Ti and AMD 7970 3GB card on 2 monitors. And use BOTH cards with OpenCL drivers. Its possible to instal the official AMD drivers ( just one card in system ) or just Nvidia, but not both of them. get mostly the card is not configured ( Nvidia ) or something this way ( standard issue with them )

Is there a way to run it eventually with just one monitor ? ( but both card running OpenCL ) in the application that i use.

Comment: If I'm not picking up on what you actually want, let me know in the comments.  I think I know what you wanted though, and it simply isn't a thing yet.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this won't work.  OpenCL isn't designed that way.  It's an abstraction layer to let you talk to differing video cards.  It doesn't beat vendors in to submission for you.

You could, however, install both drivers, design your application so that it allows multiple device/pool selections, and queue queries to both devices.  They won't magically become one opencl processing pool for you though...and I think that's what you want.

Comment: The app IS designed to use BOTH devices AMD and NVIDIA with OpenCL at least under Windows and it work flawlessly. Using it over 1 year now. But for reason that want do discuss ( indepht stuff about the photogrammetric application ) need to run it under LINUX enviroment. Can install one or other without problem, but cannot run both same time...... there is problem at it seems related to Nvidia about the proper settings( limited mode or that stuff ) , but as have searched for answer dual monitor on two diff cards IS a problem, but propable exist way to make it happen.

Comment: I don't think it used both cards for openCL out of the box without some tweaking... like this http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/6258-NVIDIA-ATI-hardware-in-the-same-Computer ... I'm just saying.

Comment: see data from LOG of the application: 

finished depth reconstruction in 393.394 seconds
Device 1 performance: 147.25 million samples/sec (CPU)
Device 2 performance: 365.626 million samples/sec (GeForce GTX 560 Ti)
Device 3 performance: 631.55 million samples/sec (Tahiti)
Total performance: 1144.43 million samples/sec
Generating mesh...

So its working and without any tweaks :-) 
thanx for the answer anyway.... But need to put both cards to work.

Comment: I don't have gear to test on.  Generally it doesn't work is the best possible answer given a lack of hardware.

Comment: Yup, but ahve seen few things about it but noone want say precisely how to do it. They say just my few things.... OK then its possible to have both cards in sytem but just ONE connected to monitor so its need not the settings hell do be done and just run it with OpenCL = will the adapter be ACTIVE without connecting to monitor ??

Comment: Hi All today will try this on 13.04 let me know if it work for you... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioMeSCoyYng